# Oracle query to sort

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by

I have values in my column as `[1_A CA 1_H 1_G CB AA AB HG]`, If i use order by clause then the output am getting is `[1_A 1_G 1_H AA AB CA CB HG]`. 
I have tried this till now

```
select distinct Plant_name from table_plants order by Plant_name
```

But I need result as `[AA AB CA CB HG 1_A 1_G 1_H]`.

Answer (score 1):

One way is you could match and put numeric characters to follow alphabets and then order by the column.

```
SELECT *
FROM table_plants 
ORDER BY CASE 
        WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(Plant_name , '[0-9]')
            THEN 2
        ELSE 1
        END
    ,Plant_name;
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/08e15/10)

If you want to consider numeric characters that start with a digit, you could make it `'^[0-9]'`.

Also, if you like to use non-regexp functions like `translate`, it should do the trick for cases like your's if underscore is present in all the numeric columns.

```
ORDER BY 
TRANSLATE(Plant_name,'x0123456789','x')
```

Answer (score 1):

This should give the desired output :

```
select  Plant_name
from table_plants order by
regexp_substr(Plant_name, '^[[:alpha:]]') ,
regexp_substr(Plant_name, '^\d*'),
regexp_substr(Plant_name, '[[:alpha:]]', 1,2)  desc nulls last,
regexp_substr(Plant_name, '\d*', 1,2) desc,
regexp_substr(Plant_name, '[[:alpha:]]') desc ;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is working. Is there any way where i can get values as [AB AA CB CA HG 1_H 1_G 1_A]

Comment: Yes, Just add desc to last `order by` like this :

 select Plant_name from
 table_plants
 order by regexp_substr(Plant_name, '^[[:alpha:]]*') , 
 regexp_substr(Plant_name, '^\d*'),
 regexp_substr(regexp_substr(Plant_name, '_[[:alpha:]]*') 
        ,'[[:alpha:]]+') desc;

Comment: Missed that alphabetical order is also changed. This should work : `select Plant_name  from
table_plants
order by regexp_substr(Plant_name, '^[[:alpha:]]') , 
regexp_substr(Plant_name, '[[:alpha:]]', 1,2) desc,
regexp_substr(Plant_name, '^\d*'),
regexp_substr(regexp_substr(Plant_name, '_[[:alpha:]]*') ,'[[:alpha:]]+') desc; `

Comment: This is working but when next character is number its not working. For example [1_A 1_G  1_D] its showing random instead of [1_G 1_D  1_A]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169563/discussion-between-sukhpal-singh-and-yasmeen).

Comment: Am sorry for providing different values. Website was not allowing me to upload question(it was saying grammar mistake) hence i used underscore. When it comes to numeric values it is still giving random values. I data i have in column is [AD AC AB AA H7 H2 H4 H3 H8 H6 H5 H9 H1 HL HJ HH HG HF 1S 1B 1G 1A]
I need to display it as [AD AC AB AA HL HJ HH HG HF H9 H8 H6 H7 H5 H4 H3 H2 H1 1S 1G 1B 1A]. Can you please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Combining `SIGN` and `ASCII` functions with `REGEXP_REPLACE`, you may get the desired results :

```
select distinct Plant_name 
  from table_plants 
 order by regexp_replace(Plant_name,'^\d*');

PLANT_NAME
----------
AA
AB
CA
CB
HG
1_A
1_G
1_H
```

[***SQL Fiddle Demo***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/08e15/1)

With respect to your last edit, you may get the desired results by :

```
select distinct Plant_name
  from table_plants 
 order by sign(50-ascii(Plant_name)),ascii(Plant_name),
          regexp_replace(Plant_name,'^\d*') desc;

PLANT_NAME
----------
AB
AA
CB
CA
HG
1_H
1_G
1_A
```

[***SQL Fiddle Demo 2***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/08e15/26)

Comment: Is there any way where i can get values as [AB AA CB CA HG 1_H 1_G 1_A].